# Hibernate Bulk Amount Data Processing

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

We are about starting a financial project which required heavily on data processing (like everyday run program to sorting, routing, filtering bulk amount of data).

My question is, Using Hibernate as JPA provider, Where it should be best to handle processing data ? Business Object or in Database batch.
More details:

1. Business Object handle most of processing logic then only trigger CRUD to Database
2. Database handle most of processing logic and CRUD to database table, Business Object handle

Which one is better approach in term of maintainability and scalability ?

Comment: A proper domain model is easier to maintain, but less performing than pure database scripts. You will have to find the good balance between both.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice. :) It is a really good starting point to plan and think further. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always start out with a proper business domain layer, and then compromise to the database script if needed.  If nothing else, it will help you work out your domain logic.

You also might find that you don't need to use a database script, and that the business object layer works just fine.

One of the big advantages of using a domain layer is that you can refactor your database without a huge change to the processing logic.  For example, if you needed to set up replicas of the database for reading lookup logic (customer info, etc), and a single master for pushing writes to, this will be easy to do if you have a domain layer, and a complete rewrite if you implement in database scripts.

Write your application, THEN optimize.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I may considered more on the Business Layer to handle most of the logic and Database simply CRUD.